# Is there way to check ping in Firefox or google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I have subscription to a proxy service but connection keeps dropping connected through FoxyProxy extension.

Is there way to check ping using Firefox or Chrome similar to Windows command prompt `ping google.com -t` for example?

Comment: You can use the logging features at `about:logging`: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/networking/http/logging.html. There is also `about:networking` but nothing like `ping` there.